# wordpress добавляет к ссылкам адрес текущей страницы

Tags: wordpress

Создал текстовое поле через metaboxes 
вывожу - оно к ссылке лепит еще и адрес текущей страницы
Пример: на странице http://site.ru/test/ добавлено поле vk.com/id1/

ставлю ссылку и вывожу

```
$textInput1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mytextinput11', true);
<a class="testimonials-link" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $textInput1; ?>" rel = "nofollow"><?php echo $textInput1; ?></a>
```

вместо ссылки типа  href="vk.com/id1/" получается href="http://site.ru/test/vk.com/id1/"
Как убрать это?

WordPress Версия 4.7.4 
Тема twentyseventeen стандартная

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это делает не вордпресс, а сам хтмл, потому что ссылка `vk.com/id1/` выглядит как [относительная](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki).

Нужно либо указывать в поле ввода полный адрес, включая `http://` или `https://`, либо добавить в пхп код, который будет проверять данные из поля и добавлять к ним недостающее начало. [Например, так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762083/6263942):

```
function addhttp($url) {
  if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
    $url = "http://" . $url;
  }
  return $url;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Правда в другом месте вылезли косяки после добавления функции, но это поправимо))

Comment: Ещё, кстати, через [esc_url](https://wp-kama.ru/function/esc_url) данные из поля прогоните. Эта функция, помимо всего прочего, некоторые опечатки исправляет. А какие косяки появились?

Comment: да я на метабокс функцию повесил, чтобы можно было писать только "id2332" или "usernick" и оно само добавляло адрес https://vk.com/. сам себе работу добавил)))